# Set `Divider` color to `OutlinedTextField` border color

Tags: colors, android-jetpack-compose

The default color for `Divider` looks awkward in my case:

[image: Divider with very less contrast]

It would be nice if it matched the border color of the text fields, but I can't figure out, how to get the default color of it.

Comment: Provide a [minimal-reproducible-example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The `Divider` takes a `color` parameter:

```
@Composable
@ComposableTarget
public fun Divider(
    modifier: Modifier,
    thickness: Dp,
    color: Color
): Unit
```

```
Divider(color = MaterialTheme.colorScheme.outline)
```

Comment: Thanks, didn't know there was a `colorScheme.outline` property